# Produce the escaped character of a character

Tags: c++

I wonder if there is a legit and simple way to write a function, which:

- takes a character as input (e.g. `'n'`)
- and returns the escaped character (e.g. `'\n'`)

without lengthy switch case forest or lookup tables.

```
char escape(char x) {

}
```

Maybe there is some binary trick, which works for ASCII characters, like clearing a bit?

[cpp reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/escape) makes it look like a daunting task and hard to get right. Especially, also because of the `\c` thingy. Should there not be a standard library function for that conversion?

Comment: there is no simple relation between `x` and `\x` for all `x`. Whats wrong with a lookuptable? After all there aren't that many of them

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number A Lookup Table was my first impulse, but then I thought "Wait a minute, maybe someone knows something more simple!"

Comment: tricks aren't simple

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number Fewer keystrokes then. And no browsing of ASCII tables and filling in numbers.

Comment: you could fit a polynomial of high enough degree and then use that ;)